# Only one JIRA issue per top-level groupId is necessary. This looks like a duplicate of OSSRH-12345, so let's track progress in that issue

Tags: sonatype, maven-central

I tried to create a repo for my 2nd artifact. but it gives me

```
Only one JIRA issue per top-level groupId is necessary. This looks like a duplicate of OSSRH-85362, so let's track progress in that issue.
```

My 1st repo group id is `io.github.cozyloon.lets`. Now i tried to create `io.github.cozyloon.RAapi` but it shows above error. any solution for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it how it works. After creating a repo with the Jira issue we don't need to create again for the new artifact. we can release that artifact under the `io.github.cozyloon`
We only need to create 1 Jira issue to create our own repo and sync it with maven central. That's all. After successful sync, we can create any artifact under this group id

ex:

1. io.github.cozyloon.lets
2. io.github.cozyloon.abc